# Display multiple files with ACF Extended

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having trouble displaying multiple files (.pdf, .docx, .xlsx etc.) on WordPress Post using ACF **File** field type with enabled "Allow multiple files" on Advanced Custom Fields Extended PRO.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
    <?php
$file = get_field('documents');
if( $file ):

    // Extract variables.
    $url = $file['url'];
    $title = $file['title'];
    $caption = $file['caption'];
    $icon = $file['icon'];

    // Display image thumbnail when possible.
    if( $file['type'] == 'image' ) {
        $icon =  $file['sizes']['thumbnail'];
    }

    // Begin caption wrap.
    if( $caption ): ?>
        <div class="wp-caption">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_attr($url); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_attr($icon); ?>" />
        <span><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></span>
    </a>

    <?php 
    // End caption wrap.
    if( $caption ): ?>
        <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo esc_html($caption); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Anyone can help me on how to display attached files on particular post?

Comment: I dont know WP, but start by adding a `print_r($file);` If you are passing multiple files, I would expect that to be an array

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/

The code on the example page worked nearly Verbatim for me.

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater_field_name', 'option') ): ?>

<ul>

<?php while( have_rows('repeater_field_name', 'option') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <li><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

I have no affiliation with that write-up except for using it myself.